# Remove Quick Settings from notification pulldown

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, notification-bar, lg, quick-settings

I've been trying to find a way to hide or disable the quick settings toggles in the notification pulldown. I'm using an LG Optimus Fuel running a rooted LG-stock Kitkat ROM (Xposed Framework is installed). Any suggestions?

Comment: Bumping this because I'd like an answer as soon as possible. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I've found my own answer. The Xposed module "LG G2 TweaksBox" works with the LG Optimus Fuel for reasons unknown and allows changing what's visible in the notification pulldown, as well as the every other option of the module. Hopefully this provides help to others with the same issue.